# USB audio device not detected

Tags: sound, usb, devices

I've been having problems with USB sound for some time (it used to work
about 6 months ago). I find that any USB sound device that I connect is
not recognised, and is not listed by aplay -l

I've tried disabling pulseaudio.  I've tried purging and re-installing
alsa-base, pulseaudio, and pavucontrol.  To no avail.

I'm using 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Hi, following etiquette could you convert your solution to an answer (rather than in-line with the question) and mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[Solution given by OP:](https://askubuntu.com/posts/354090/revisions)

> 12.04 does not have the needed kernel module snd-usb-hiface this is introduced in the 3.11.1 kernel and installing that on 12.04 gives USB sound for my equipment. How to install the 3.11.1 kernel is given here:- [installing 3.11.1 kernel](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/09/kernel-3-11-1-released-install-upgrade-in-ubuntu-linux-mint/)